# Does Blender 2.72 work with the Three.JS add-on?

Tags: windows-7, three.js, export, blender

I try to setup the add-on: `io_mesh_threejs`:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_mesh_threejs

Tried the following:

- Setup Blender 2.72 on Windows 7
- I followed the hints (used raw files, init in root or `io_mesh_threejs` folder, load from .zip, etc.).
- I tried what I found in different posts in the web, e.g. [Three.JS plugin for Blender not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731646/three-js-plugin-for-blender-not-working)

Nothing appears under Blender /Prefer./addon
The add-on is not shown in Blender.

Was anybody able to run this add-on on Blender 2.72? Does it work in this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the folder to put addons in might have moved.  I'm on a Mac, but had a problem getting the Three.js exporter to work with Blender 2.72 as well.  It turns out that after moving the `io_mesh_threejs` directory into `/Applications/blender.app/Content/Resources/2.72/scripts/addons/`, it worked.  I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent would be, but that might at least get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hallo Alex thanks a lot for your hint. As i could not find a solution i implemented a workaround ( using 2D ExtrudeGeomerty instead of 3D ConvexGeometry in my threeJS webGL Project). I´m pretty sure u´re right. I also tried some different folder ( weeks ago ) but unfortunately without success. So the moment i take the Blender-Generated-Object as option for furture use.